ESLint Stylistic is ignoring ts files
I'm using the new ESLint flat style with @stylistic/eslint-plugin but it fails to detect ts files and when I try to run it directly against a ts file it gives me the error:
warning  File ignored because no matching configuration was supplied

Here are my files:
eslint.config.mjs
import stylistic from "@stylistic/eslint-plugin";

export default [
    {
        plugins : {
            "@stylistic" : stylistic,
        },
        rules : {
            "@stylistic/comma-dangle" : ["error", "always-multiline"],
            "@stylistic/eol-last" : ["error", "always"],
            "@stylistic/indent" : [
                "error",
                "tab",
                {
                    "SwitchCase" : 1,
                },
            ],
            "@stylistic/key-spacing" : ["error", { "beforeColon" : true }],
            "@stylistic/linebreak-style" : [
                "error",
                "unix",
            ],
            "@stylistic/quotes" : [
                "error",
                "double",
                {
                    "allowTemplateLiterals" : true,
                    "avoidEscape" : true,
                },
            ],
            "@stylistic/semi" : [
                "error",
                "always",
            ],
            "@stylistic/type-annotation-spacing" : [
                "error",
                {
                    "before" : true,
                },
            ],
        },
    },
];

tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
      "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
      "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
      "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
      "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
      "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }

dependencies
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.8.0",
    "@stylistic/eslint-plugin": "^2.6.0",
    "appium": "^2.11.2",
    "eslint": "^9.8.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "webdriverio": "^8.39.1"
  }


By default, ESLint includes all files with the extensions .js, .cjs and .mjs. If you want to lint files with other extensions, such as .ts, you need to specify them via files. Source: ESLint config docs. Updated config:
import stylistic from "@stylistic/eslint-plugin";

export default [
    {
        plugins: {
            "@stylistic" : stylistic,
        },
        files: ["**/*.ts"],
        rules: {
            // your rules
        },
    },
]


I get a minor issue with this now. I have a piece of code that looks something like this: const o = { key : "abc" as const } and eslint gives me the error Parsing error: Unexpected token as |eslint|  in vscode, like it doesn't actually register it's typescript

@A.L I am not very familiar with using TypeScript together with the default ESLint parser, however you could try using the TypeScript ESLint parser. If this doesn't work, maybe you should ask a new question.
